# I am having troubles displaying a View as a popup window for a ToS

Tags: java, android

First post here, sorry if I do(did?) something wrong.

I have been developing an android application for a few weeks now and decided to add a User Agreement/Terms of Service to it. I created an xml called agreement.xml, and found this code...

https://gist.github.com/slaypni/3817116
(I found it on here somewhere actually but I couldnt find the original, this one is extremely similar, just a different class name.)

This worked perfectly for me for awhile but I recently altered a little bit of the code that calls it and tested on a new device and there is a strange issue.

I call it via...

```
View licenseView = View.inflate(UI, R.layout.agreement, null);

PopUpView ToS = new PopUpView(UI, licenseView);
ToS.show();
```

I run the code once on first application execution (and alter a few things such as button text and visibilities) to collect some user information. I then call it again after everything is done to display the newly downloaded agreement. The second time around it appears that none of the following code is working.

```
checkboxAcceptLicense = (CheckBox)UI.findViewById(R.id.checkLicenseAgreement);
textviewLicense = (TextView)UI.findViewById(R.id.textviewLicenseAgreement);

textviewLicense.setText(agreement);

buttonOK= (Button)UI.findViewById(R.id.buttonOK);
buttonCancel = (Button)UI.findViewById(R.id.buttonCancel);
etName = (EditText)UI.findViewById(R.id.etName);
etNumber = (EditText)UI.findViewById(R.id.etNumber);            

etName.setText(prefs.getString("Name", null));
etNumber.setText(prefs.getString("Number", null));

buttonCancel.setOnClickListener(cancel);
buttonOK.setOnClickListener(accept);
```

which immediately follows the first block. I assume the issue is with the class I am using to display the item as a popup as I had some strange null pointer exceptions from it before. Currently there are no errors or anything, the code runs and the logging all around it shows up but the buttons are unresponsive and the text isnt set.

Thanks for any and all help!

Edit: I removed my null check because I assume this is evidence of the problem. On the second call it crashes with a nullpointerexception at line 74 of the popup class. I feel like it is a problem with the inflater but I really do not have a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to make a dialog instead it comes with a positive and negative buttons (ok/cancel)

and a content area which you can customize as you need check out this [LINK](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Comment: Well that worked well. I had to play with it a bit to get it to display like I needed it to but I didn't think you could include all the bits I needed in a dialog, Thanks!

On that.. I would still love for someone to tell me what the issue was with the previous method. I dont like not knowing what happened just in case I run into it again